# Highlight selected text in HTML.div or Dcc.Markdown in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to implement a keyword search approach in Dash where if the user types a certain keyword, it gets highlighted in the HTML.div or dcc.Markdown.

I have tried to enclose the keyword in dcc.Markdown using `keyword`, but it is not what I am looking for. Also for some reason the `` doesnt really highlight the text but rather makes it look tiny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [html.Mark](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/mark)
if you put the text in a `html.Div` component.

You  could do something like this:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

text = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
"""

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            id="text-container",
            children=[html.Div(text)],
        ),
        dcc.Input(id="search-input"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("text-container", "children"),
    Input("search-input", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def search(search_value):
    output = html.Div([text])

    if search_value:
        sequences = text.split(search_value)
        i = 1
        while i < len(sequences):
            sequences.insert(i, html.Mark(search_value))
            i += 2

        output.children = sequences

    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

So the idea above is to create a callback which is called when your search input
value changes. When the callback is called and the search value is not equal
to an empty string I split the text with the search value as the delimiter.

```
sequences = text.split(search_value)
# equals: ['\n', ' ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n']
# if search_value equals: Lorem
```

So now we have sequences of text where the search value doesn't match.
In between these sequences we can put the sequences that did match
the search value surrounded by the `html.Mark` function, that is
what the `while` loop is doing in the example above.

Now as far as I know you can't do this for
the `Markdown` component, because this only takes strings and
not other Dash components. You could do something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("text-container", "children"),
    Input("search-input", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def search(search_value):
    new_text = text
    if search_value:
        new_text = text.replace(search_value, f"<mark>{search_value}</mark>")

    return dcc.Markdown(
        new_text,
        dangerously_allow_html=True,
    )
```

But the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/markdown) says
the following about `dangerously_allow_html`:

> A boolean to control raw HTML escaping. Setting HTML from code is risky because it's easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack.